# usage of tag's in css class names

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having the following problem. Wordpress generates following code based on a String. The String accepts tag's but not " ". So I can't give it a class name or id. Now I need a specific mark-up for some cells, I defined that mark-up in a css file  :

```
<td class="decoded_<i>1_year_warrenty</i>"> ☑ </td>
```

Now I need to make the color of the ☑ white. Following code works for classes without the  tag

```
.decoded_<i>1_year_warrenty</i> {
color: white;}
```

Is there a method to let the browser know that it's part of the class name and not a tag.

Comment: The class name cannot contain `<` or `>` or `/`.

Comment: This must be preprocessed and then sent to the browser after changing those classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use these characters in a CSS class name, they're simply not valid.

See the following SO question:

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

---

If wordpress is generating this then I would imagine it's a limitation of the system and that you'll need to remove some italic styling somewhere in the CMS.

Answer (score 2):

The class name cannot contain `<` or `>` or `/`. So please change the code that outputs invalid Class Name instead of making a CSS for that.

Maintaining the right HTML / CSS syntax is important than hacking the browser to work.